# Получить root-доступ на Linux'e!

Tags: root

Есть машина с ограниченным физическим доступом. Не могу использовать диски/флешки/дискеты.Необходимо получить пароль рута.Способ с rw init /bin/bash не пройдет, так как на грабе стоит пароль. Граб версии 0.97. Стоит OpenSUSE 11.Какие будут предложения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самый простой способ получить рутовый доступ - single-user mode. Дописываете в загрузчике ключ -s и voila! Производите с системой любые действия. Если же на GRUB'е стоит пароль, то единственный реальный способ - эскалация прав (т.е. нужно искать уязвимый сервис операционной системы и взламывать его).

Comment: А если загрузиться с Live CD? GRUB не даст?

Comment: Нет возможности использовать CD.Как я загружусь?

Comment: Не дочитал вопрос, прошу прощения.

Answer (score 0):

Самое простое -- спросить пароль у того, кто ставил систему и задавал этот пароль. А так скорее всего это сделать нереально, это же root... Ну, можно еще погуглить на тему сброс пароля в Линуксе...

З.Ы. А у меня ни разу не требовал пароль для флешки, только для системных настроек... Видно, у Вас пользователь с минимальными привилегиями...